# Pandas - df['A'].isnull() vs df['A']=='' difference

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

As title says, I'm bit confused between the usage isnull() and ==''. sometimes when empty columns are added to a dataframe, isnull() does not work.

```
FDF = pd.DataFrame()
FDF['A'] = ''
print (FDF.loc[FDF['A'].isnull()])
```

but in the same case following works.

```
print (FDF.loc[FDF['A']==''])
```

is it because the way I added a blank column in a dataframe? if so, what is the correct way to add an empty column ?

Answer (score 2):

In `pandas` `''` is not equal to `np.nan`

```
''==np.nan
Out[51]: False
```

That is why when you do the `isnull` check it will return `False` for empty string

Also, when you assign it assign a empty value series to the dataframe

```
FDF.A
Out[54]: Series([], Name: A, dtype: object)
```

---

Correct way to assign value

```
FDF['A'] = ['']
FDF
Out[59]: 
  A
0
```

---

All above is due to the empty dataframe assignment, after we have the index value not empty for the dataframe

We can do

```
FDF['A'] = ['']
FDF['B'] = ''

FDF
Out[64]: 
  A B
0
```

Comment: what is the correct way to add a blank column ? or update the blank column after adding ? for my use case, sometimes a column is expected in the input file, if not then add an empty column.

Comment: @Prish you may also want to try reindex